# Multiple select. Symfony Form

Tags: javascript, php, css, symfony, formbuilder

How to select multiple entity?

My Symfony form code

```
    ->add('typeContact', 'entity', array(
        'required'=>false,
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'class' => 'App\MyBundle\Entity\TypeContact'
    ))
```

I got this result,

[image]

But I want this type.

[image]

How can I get this type. I try `expanded => false`.
Any one can help please ?

Comment: is this using select2 - https://select2.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

This links will help you create tags like you want : http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/ OR https://select2.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to represent choice list with ability to check multiple values in Symfony is a checkboxes.

To use library like [select2.github.io](http://select2.github.io) you need to override `choice_widget_expanded` block in your form template. To learn how to override templates follow this link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html